# Servlet to JDBC through JNDI

Tags: java, jdbc, jndi

I want to look up an object from a Servlet to JDBC through JNDI.
What is the  exact code for this process?

Answer (score 3):

may depend on your servlet container:

```
String initialContext = "java:comp/env";  
Context env = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup(initialContext);
Object o = env.lookup(name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code in try block

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) 
initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) 
envContext.lookup("jdbc/UsersDB");
Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
```

**add this on context. xml**

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/UsersDB"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="30"
    maxWait="10000"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.56:1433;DatabaseName=testdb1;"
    username="uname"
    password="pwd"
    />
```

**web.xml**

```
 <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/UsersDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```